# Creating map object angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a map `daySubjects` and `subject` array i also have `days` array to store '`Sunday to Saturday`'
i have to create json like this using these variables

```
{
"daySubjects": {
    "MONDAY": {
        "subject": [

        ]
    },
    "TUESDAY": {
        "subject": [

        ]
    },
    "WEDNESDAY": {
        "subject": [

        ]
    },
    "THURSDAY": {
        "subject": [

        ]
    },
    "FRIDAY": {
        "subject": [

        ]
    },
    "SATURDAY": {
        "subject": [

        ]
    },
    "SUNDAY": {
        "subject": [

        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: cool. But why is it angularjs? You may want to check [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library, that provides a nice collection of methods to handle common tasks over collections.

Comment: angular or javascript anything is okay,can you just show how to make this atleast for one day using the mentioned variables?

Comment: I am not able to achieve this i tried `var subject=[]`  `$scope.timetable.daySubjects["sunday"]=subject`

Comment: Why these guys are downvoting,please mention my mistake i m a newbe

Comment: I can only guess for the reason, but [here is what you should consider when you ask a question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . I think, the biggest issue is that its a fairly trivial problem, and you just delegated it instead of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understand the qustion correctly, here is the sample plain javascript code:

```
var days = ["sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat"];
var result = {
    daySubjects : {}
};
days.forEach(
    function(i){ 
        result.daySubjects[i] = { subject:[] };
    }
);
```

After execution this lines, result object will contain:

```
{
    "daySubjects": {
        "sun": {
            "subject": []
        },
        "mon": {
            "subject": []
        },
        "tue": {
            "subject": []
        },
        "wed": {
            "subject": []
        },
        "thu": {
            "subject": []
        },
        "fri": {
            "subject": []
        },
        "sat": {
            "subject": []
        }
    }
}
```

In javascript, you have to take care that objects that you are referring to, are defined. For example:

```
var test = {};

// fails because test.x is not defined
test.x[0] = 10;

//works cause you create array object before using it
test.x = [];
test.x[0] = 10;
```

What makes it easier, however, is that you can define a the whole nested JSON object structure in one go.